# compact nl2br accounting for both

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make a function similar to [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) except that I wish this function to only work if `\n` **does not** follow `<br />` . I wish these scenarioes

```
*\n*       ->    <br>
*<br>\n*   ->   nothing
*<br>*   ->   nothing
```

In pseudo code I *was* thinking;

```
if (regex !== <br>\n && regex === *<br>)
```

but this makes no sense unless the `!<br>` bit is within the regex itself. Simply put regexes are melting my brain figuring out excluding regexes within regexes..

Comment: `/n` - that should be `\n` and you talk about "ln2br", you mean "nl2br", right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes. Friday evening typos...

Comment: No problemo. Now, `\n` is a hidden (server) file character unlike an HTML `<br>` which is a tag, so I think what you're trying to achieve is going to be quite tricky. I for one don't have an answer for it. Let's wait and see if someone else has a trick up their sleeve ;)

Comment: I've tried to answer, but you may want to help out a bit more in your question by giving us an example of some input and the resultant output you want to get from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, something like:

```
<?php
  $test = "This\nis\na<br>\ntest";
  $result = preg_replace('/(?<!<br>)\n/', "<br>", $test);
  print_r($result);
```

Result:

> ```
> This<br>is<br>a<br>
> test
> ```

This uses a [regular expression feature called "negative lookbehind"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to see if the newline has the `<br>` in front of it.

Comment: This works nicely, but I also need it (or a different regexp) to ad-hear to the (newly edited) 3rd scenario: `*<br>*   ->   nothing` Essentially so that <br>s aren't repeated